# Google Play Services Library Error in OneSignal, why?

Tags: java, android-studio, onesignal

i did add OneSignal based on the documentation in my application.
Everything works for me.
However, I can't send notifications to some devices because it says: Google Play Services Library Error (image included)

What I've already tried:

- I created a new project in OneSignal (new app id)
- the AndroidManifest.xml file contains:

  ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  ```

I don't know what to do now.... :(

[Google Play Services Library Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvjmA.jpg)

UPDATE:
only appears on some devices, on first start-up.
Error message:

```
  E / OneSignal: Error Getting FCM Tokenjava.io.IOException: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
```

If you reopen the application, the error will disappear.

Comment: It says "Check the Logcat for more details".  You should *start* by doing that.

Comment: This is devices not my...

Comment: Hello @web216 Please how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and recompiling the application